# Use On-Premises Multi-valued custom Attribute to Create Dynamic Security Group

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have created a custom multi-valued Unicode String attribute on-premises by extending the AD schema (AD 2016). I have sync'd the attribute to Azure AD with AAD connect. I can reference it in membership rules when creating Dynamic Groups in the portal.

The attribute is extension_{GUID}_MyAttribute. On-premises there are 2 items itemA, itemB in the custom attribute for users.

None of the following work in my Dynamic Group

```
(user.extension_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_MyAttribute -any (_ -contains "itemA"))
(user.extension_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_MyAttribute -contains "itemA")
(user.extension_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_MyAttribute -any (_ -contains "itemA" -and "itemB"))
```

What am I missing? I am following the MSFT article here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-dynamic-membership#multi-value-properties

Thank you

EDIT: Just to give more context. I am using a REST technical profile in B2C custom policy to get membership information about this group using REST API calls. There is a legacy on-premises app that populates AD attributes used to drive membership.

Comment: Please share how your custom multi-valued Unicode String attribute is shown under your Azure AD user. Maybe you can get the user information in [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and share a screenshot of the custom attribute in the response.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I don't see the extension attribute at all even when using Graph Explorer. I have it populated for a user on-premises but when looking at the user in the Graph Explorer, it is not one of their attributes

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't been able to see what the Multi-valued attributes you sync to AAD is like, it seems that this is a currently known limitation.

Please see the second **Note** tip in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-directory-extensions#customize-which-attributes-to-synchronize-with-azure-ad).

> Although Azure AD Connect supports synchronizing multi-valued Active
> Directory attributes to Azure AD as multi-valued directory extensions,
> there is currently no way to retrieve/consume the data uploaded in
> multi-valued directory extension attributes.

Comment: Hey Allen, if I am reading the note correctly, I cant use the the MV attributes in DSGs either?

Comment: @Bandz Yes. I think so.